# navigate route with querystring

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Will `Backbone.Router.navigate` set `test` to `true`:

```
var test = false;

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'posts': 'showPosts'
  },
  showPosts: function () {
    test = true;
  }
});

router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();

router.navigate('posts?foo=3', {trigger: true});

assert.ok(test);
```

Eg, will `posts?foo=3` fragment will match the `posts` route by default, or do I have to set another route for that, for example: `posts?*querystring`?

Thank you

PS: I know there exist the [backbone-query-parameters](https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters) but I want to know just for backbone.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem     

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254230/backbone-router-ignoring-search-route

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to add another route with that expecting parameter :

```
routes: {
    'posts?foo=:foo' : 'showPosts',
    'posts': 'showPosts'
},
showPosts: function (foo) {
    if(typeof foo != 'undefined'){
       // foo parameters was passed
    }
    test = true;
}
```

**update**
You could define the general route to return all the query string and then parse it in the handler :

```
routes: {
   'posts': 'showPosts',
   'posts?*queryString' : 'showPosts'
},
showPosts: function (queryString) {
    var params = parseQueryString(queryString);
    if(params.foo){
        // foo parameters was passed
    }
}  
...
// and the function that parses the query string can be something like : 
function parseQueryString(queryString){
    var params = {};
    if(queryString){
        _.each(
            _.map(decodeURI(queryString).split(/&/g),function(el,i){
                var aux = el.split('='), o = {};
                if(aux.length >= 1){
                    var val = undefined;
                    if(aux.length == 2)
                        val = aux[1];
                    o[aux[0]] = val;
                }
                return o;
            }),
            function(o){
                _.extend(params,o);
            }
        );
    }
    return params;
}
```

**update 2**

Here's [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jMeV3/6/) to see the code in action.

Comment: In one case you define the most specific route (`posts?foo=:foo`) first, and on the other case on second position: doesn't order matter?

Comment: no , it doesn't affect how routes are being applied. It's just a matter of preference. BTW, I've tested & updated the function and now it works great.

Comment: I see this demo working, but for reasons I still cannot fathom, this does not work for me. Using these route constructions, queryString is always undefined.

Comment: I see what the issue is - while you're able to execute the route by passing true to navigate, this still doesn't not work with history correctly. Additionally, having to pass true to navigate is less than ideal as it requires my router execute navigation rather than simply executing interpreted routes.

Comment: This answer is getting far from the initial question... Your answer is now more a how to parse a querystring...

Comment: This works only when triggering Router.navigate('posts?foo=bar',{trigger:true,replace:true}); with replace:true. Is there a way for it to work when you go directly to the url?

Comment: Matching on the whole query string **does not work** when you are using URI encoded query parameters (e.g. "foo=Max%20%26%20Moritz") because backbone.js only expects full path fragments and already calls decodeURIComponent on every route parameters. Therefore parsing the query string later will not work correctly.

Answer (score 18):

Just to complement the previous answers, instead of defining two routes that have the same callback, like:

```
routes: {
    'posts': 'showPosts',
    'posts?*querystring': 'showPosts'
}
```

You could have only one route to keep the code cleaner:

```
routes: {
    'posts(?*querystring)': 'showPosts'
}
```

Comment: **Matching on the whole query string does not work** when you are using URI encoded query parameters (e.g. "foo=Max%20%26%20Moritz") because backbone.js only expects full path fragments and already calls decodeURIComponent on every route parameters. Therefore parsing the query string later will not work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Backbone docs:

> Routes can contain parameter parts, :param, which match a single URL component between slashes; and splat parts *splat, which can match any number of URL components.

If you still want to keep the functionality without the matching you can define two routes

```
routes: {
  'posts': 'showPosts',
  'posts?*querystring': 'showPosts'
}

showPosts: function(querystring) {
  if (querystring) {
    // here you can parse your querystring, for your case the querystring variable is 
    // 'foo=3'
  }
  //here you'll show posts according to the querystring (or lack thereof)      
}
```

Comment: Is `?*` without a name for the splat `?*querystring` ok?

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Backbone 1? Cz it's not triggering any route action after I added the '?*query'

Comment: The answer was made almost a year ago. But the docs or changelogs don't hint towards any reasons for this not to work

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Having a route with ?*queryString not only doesn't capture the queryString variable, but if I have this and not the route without the query string, the route doesn't get interpreted at all.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another take, still using lodash (underscore).  Removed the _.map, added a bit of verbosity to the variables, and stripped out the starting '?' if present:

```
function parseQueryString(queryString)
{
    if (!_.isString(queryString))
        return
    queryString = queryString.substring( queryString.indexOf('?') + 1 )
    var params = {}
    var queryParts = decodeURI(queryString).split(/&/g)
    _.each(queryParts, function(val)
        {
            var parts = val.split('=')
            if (parts.length >= 1)
            {
                var val = undefined
                if (parts.length == 2)
                    val = parts[1]
                params[parts[0]] = val
            }
        })
    return params
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, should have got more attention imo

Answer (score 1):

RFC 3986 "syntax for URIs" states that query parameters shold come before  hash fragment.

> In URIs a hashmark # introduces the optional fragment near the end of the URL. The generic RFC 3986 syntax for URIs also allows an optional query part introduced by a question mark ?. In URIs with a query and a fragment, the fragment follows the query.

I have this issue handling a redirect I am getting from the server i.e. "http://foo.com/main.html?error=errormessage#site".  I would like to route on the query but can't see a way to write the backbone route expression to handle this url.  For now I just route on the hash and check for a query by parsing location.search.