# Backbone Router Ignoring search route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

In need of some help!

I'm trying to get my Backbone router to match this route:

`http://localhost:5150/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=&location=Norfolk%2C+VA&commit=Search`

..And nothing is working. Very frustrating!
This is my first try at Backbone, so advice would be awesome.

```
 '/search_results?*': 'search_results'
  # NOPE

 '/search_results?foo=:foo': 'search_results'
  # NOPE

 '/search_results?foo*': 'search_results'
  # NOPE

 '/search_results?*queryString': 'search_results'
  # NOPE

 'search_results?*queryString': 'search_results'
  # NOPE

 'search_results?*': 'search_results'
 # NOPE

 'search_results?foo=:foo': 'search_results'
 # NOPE

 'search_results?foo*': 'search_results'
 # NOPE

'/search_results': 'search_results'
 # NOPE SERIOUSLY??

 '/search_results': 'search_results'
 # WTF!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 ':search_results?*': 'search_results'
 # NOPE

 ':search_results?:querystring': 'search_results'
 # NOPE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [navigate route with querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671400/navigate-route-with-querystring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? It should work without a leading colon, hash or slash in the route.

```
'search_results(?:queryString)': 'search_results'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey... Backbone routes generally detect route path by # keyword as far as I know..correct me if I'm wrong. So to make the things work in your case do the following things.

1) Put the # keyword like #/search_results?....

2) Now define your route as "search_results?:queryString"

This should work :)

Comment: Thanks @Sadik, is there anyway this could work with pushstate

`Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)`