# possible to do params in backbone routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was looking at routes in backbone and I was wondering if I can do the following:

```
routes: {
    '': 'posts',
    'posts?page=:page': 'posts'
}
```

This would allow me to do just a plain index of posts  and also add pagination to that index of posts.

Is this something that is ok or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be possible; http://stackoverflow.com/a/11671457/444991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using a query parameter a requirement? If not, you can use the Router's param functionality:

```
routes: {
    '': 'posts',
    "page/:page": "posts"   // #page/N
}
```