# How to get url parameters in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, query-string, backbone-routing

I'm using Backbone with Marionette.

I have a link `<a>` tag where I'm passing few parameters, how can I extract those values in other pages using Backbone?

```
<a href="http://localhost.com:8080/help/?name=matth&age=25&email=matt@gmail.com">View Details</a>
```

Address Bar url:

```
http://localhost.com:8080/help/?name=matth&age=25&email=matt@gmail.com 44
```

Using Php, this is straightforward:

```php
$Url = $_GET['state']."#".$_GET['city'];
```

How can I achieve it within my Backbone app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigate route with querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671400/navigate-route-with-querystring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the route is defined with something like this:

```
'help/:name&:age&:email' : 'help'
```

Then you can access those params in the **`help` function** just by defining them in the signature of the method (within the **backbone router**),

```
help: function(name, age, email) {
    // do whatever you want with the params
}
```

In your case, this will give you params like this:

```
name="XXX" age="XXX"
```

So the proper routing would be

```
'help/?(name=:name)(&age=:age)(&email=:email)' : 'help'
```

Where parentheses make a part optional.

[Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes)

> Routes can contain parameter parts, `:param`

---

Note that the order is important and the following url wouldn't trigger the route callback. Notice the `email` and `age` params placement.

```
help/?name=test&email=test%40example.com&age=6
```

In order to trigger a route regardless of the number of params and their ordering, take a look at how to [parse the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671400/navigate-route-with-querystring) in the route function, but that won't always work.

Comment: Be aware that with this route, the params order is important and none are optional. They can be made optional with parentheses `help/?(name=:name)(&age=:age)` but a different ordering won't trigger the route.

Comment: The parentheses should be in the route string, not in the URL. What I meant is that an URL like `help/?name=test&email=test%40example.com&age=6` would fail even though it's a valid URL since query string parameters order is not relevant by design.